# iOS Simulator does not play sound

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, ios-simulator

On XCode 6, everything works well on device, but on simulator, sound is not played.

There is my swift code :

```
var url =  NSURL(string: "http://my.url.com/sound.mp3")
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
// Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
self.player = AVAudioPlayer(data: data, error: nil)
self.player.prepareToPlay()
self.player.delegate = self
self.player.volume = 1
self.player.play()
```

There is the log :

```
ERROR:     98: Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate

ERROR:     100: Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'

WARNING:   230: The input device is 0x0; '(null)'

WARNING:   234: The output device is 0x26; 'AppleHDAEngineOutputDP:3,0,1,1:0:{2D4C-092D-00000000}'

ERROR:     400: error '!obj'

ERROR:     113: * * * NULL AQIONode object

ERROR:     180: EXCEPTION thrown ('!dev'): -

ERROR:     703: Can't make UISound Renderer

ERROR:     >aqsrv> 70: Exception caught in (null) - error -1

ERROR:     180: EXCEPTION thrown ('!dev'): -

ERROR:     >aqsrv> 70: Exception caught in (null) - error -1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752192/error-dat-trying-to-set-the-null-audio-devices-sample-rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to get `device's sample rate` from simulator, which is not possible.

#### *Because simulator is not a hardware. Its a software.*

So some hardware functionality will not able to simulated with it.

It can not do the following:

1. Open Camera
2. Play sounds
3. Gyrometer
4. Accelerometer
5. Shake effect
6. Receive push notifications

And many more which required device hardware acceleration.

**You need to test this in real device.**

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The simulator can play sounds. The probable cause to the error is that the Mac doesn't have a built in microphone, therefore the input device is null. This never happens on a real iPhone or iPad device of course that have a fixed built in input. A workaround for this problem is to make OS X show an input device i.e. plug something to the audio line in.

Comment: Sometimes restart the simulator could solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem, the comment from [@Matti Jokipii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443311/ios-simulator-does-not-play-sound#comment48461438_27444073), helped me a lot.

You need to have a sound input enabled, so your Mac doesn't give you the null exception.
Go To System Preferences > Sound. And Check you have some input connected. If not, you will have to add a microfone, and re-rerun the app.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. Just quit and start again to Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The answers already posted here led me in the right direction, but I also had to choose an "Audio Input" other than the default microphone on the simulator itself. I chose the microphone on my headset, and then I was able to play Audio using the Web Audio API from Safari in the simulator.

Got to I/O -> Audio Input -> Select a microphone.

You may also have to restart the simulator.

[image: Instructions on how to change the Audio Input settings on the iOS simulator]